# jquery function not returning html to second function

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfc, coldfusion-10

I am building a select in one function(2) then calling it in another function(1) where I pass the values needed to build the function and select the proper approver. Everything works except passing back the html to function(1).

**function(1)**

```
function loadTravelRules(id){

    $.ajax({type: "GET",url: "CFCs/myapprovers.cfc",dataType: "json",data: {method: "MYAPPROVERS_RLUz",MYAPPROVERSID: id
            },success: function(response){
                var rdata = response.DATA;
                var str = '<ul>';
                for (var i = 0; i < rdata.length; i++) {
                    var aid = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('MYAPPROVERSID')];
                    var auditor = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('DEPTAUDITAPPROVEREMPLID')];
                    var firstApprover = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('FIRSTAPPROVEREMPLID')];
                    var secondApprover = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('SECONDAPPROVEREMPLID')];
                    var thirdApprover = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('THIRDAPPROVEREMPLID')];
                    var firstDivApprover = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('FIRSTDIVAPPROVEREMPLID')];
                    var secondDivApprover = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('SECONDDIVAPPROVEREMPLID')];
                    var deptOverRide = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('DEPTOVERRIDEEMPLID')];
                    var title = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('APPROVALRULE')];

                    var auditorSelect = deptApproverSelect(id=aid,nameType="timekeeper",eid=auditor);

                str += '<li>Auditor: '+auditorSelect+'</li>';
                str += '<li>First Approver: '+firstApprover+'</li>';
                str += '<li>Second Approver: '+secondApprover+'</li>';
                str += '<li>Third Approver: '+thirdApprover+'</li>';
                str += '<li>First Div. Approver: '+firstDivApprover+'</li>';
                str += '<li>Second Div. Approver: '+secondDivApprover+'</li>';
                str += '<li>Dept. Override: '+deptOverRide+'</li>';
                }
             str += '</ul>';
             $('#manageApprovers').dialog({
                title: title+' Rules',
                modal:true
             }).html(str);
            }
        })
}
```

**function(2)**

```
function deptApproverSelect(id,nameType,eid){
    var deptid = <cfoutput>#qGetMyDept.DIV_DEPARTMENTID#</cfoutput>;

    $.ajax({type: "GET",url: "CFCs/approvers.cfc",dataType: "json",async: false,data: {method: "DEPTAPPROVER_RLUz",deptid: deptid
        },success: function(response){
            var data = response.DATA;
            var selectApprover = '<select id="'+nameType+'_'+id+'" name="'+nameType+'">';
            selectApprover += '<option value="" selected="selected">Select Approver</option>';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var display = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('FULL_NAME')];
                    var emplid = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('EMPLID')];
                    if(emplid==eid){
                        var selected = 'selected="selected"';
                    }else{
                        var selected = '';
                    }
                    selectApprover += '<option value="'+emplid+'"'+selected+'>'+display+'</option>';
                }
                selectApprover += '</select>';
                console.log(selectApprover)

        }
    })
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you expand on what is not working? What are you expecting? What are you seeing? Have you checked the data that is returned from the function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
function loadTravelRules(id){
$.ajax({type: "GET",url: "CFCs/myapprovers.cfc",dataType: "json",data: {method: "MYAPPROVERS_RLUz",MYAPPROVERSID: id
        },success: function(response){
            var rdata = response.DATA;
            var str = '<ul">';
            for (var i = 0; i < rdata.length; i++) {
                var aid = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('MYAPPROVERSID')];
                var auditor = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('DEPTAUDITAPPROVEREMPLID')];
                var firstApprover = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('FIRSTAPPROVEREMPLID')];
                var secondApprover = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('SECONDAPPROVEREMPLID')];
                var thirdApprover = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('THIRDAPPROVEREMPLID')];
                var firstDivApprover = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('FIRSTDIVAPPROVEREMPLID')];
                var secondDivApprover = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('SECONDDIVAPPROVEREMPLID')];
                var deptOverRide = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('DEPTOVERRIDEEMPLID')];
                var title = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('APPROVALRULE')];
            str += '<li>Auditor: <span id="auditor"></span></li>';
            str += '<li>First Approver: <span id="firstApprover"></span></li>';
            str += '<li>Second Approver: <span id="secondApprover"></span></li>';
            str += '<li>Third Approver: <span id="thirdApprover"></span></li>';
            str += '<li>First Div. Approver: <span id="firstDivApprover"></span></li>';
            str += '<li>Second Div. Approver: <span id="secondDivApprover"></span></li>';
            str += '<li>Dept. Override: <span id="deptOverRide""></span></li>';
            }
         str += '</ul>';
         $('#manageApprovers').dialog({
            title: title+' Rules',
            width:330,
            modal:true
         }).html(str);
            deptApproverSelect(id=aid,nameType="auditor",eid=auditor);
            deptApproverSelect(id=aid,nameType="firstApprover",eid=firstApprover);
            deptApproverSelect(id=aid,nameType="secondApprover",eid=secondApprover);
            deptApproverSelect(id=aid,nameType="thirdApprover",eid=thirdApprover);
            deptApproverSelect(id=aid,nameType="firstDivApprover",eid=firstDivApprover);
            deptApproverSelect(id=aid,nameType="secondDivApprover",eid=secondDivApprover);
            deptApproverSelect(id=aid,nameType="deptOverRide",eid=deptOverRide);
        }
    })
```

}

function deptApproverSelect(id,nameType,eid){
    var deptid = #qGetMyDept.DIV_DEPARTMENTID#;
    $.ajax({type: "GET",url: "CFCs/approvers.cfc",dataType: "json",async: false,data: {method: "DEPTAPPROVER_RLUz",deptid: deptid
        },success: function(response){
            var data = response.DATA;
            var selectApprover = '';
            selectApprover += 'Select Approver';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var display = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('FULL_NAME')];
                    var emplid = response.DATA[i][response.COLUMNS.indexOf('EMPLID')];
                    if(emplid==eid){
                        var selected = 'selected="selected"';
                    }else{
                        var selected = '';
                    }
                    selectApprover += ''+display+'';
                }
                selectApprover += '';
                $('#'+nameType).html(selectApprover);
        }
    })
}